# To what application does com~apple~shoebox belong to?

Tags: icloud

Looking at `~/Library/Mobile Documents` I see a folder named `com~apple~shoebox`. What application does it belong to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to @[Cocoanetics](https://twitter.com/Cocoanetics/), [Ole Begemann](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/) (under `ShoeboxUISerice and WebViewService`) and this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110210/267892), "Shoebox" was Apple's codename/inside name for [Passbook](https://twitter.com/Cocoanetics/statuses/251680173416660993)!

Answer (score 0):

`com~apple~shoebox` is used by **Wallet** on iOS to store and sync some non-sensitive files via iCloud. (The folder does not contain secured data such as the Wallet items themselves.)

`com~apple~shoebox` appears in the UI for both iOS and macOS as `iCloud Drive > Wallet`. (Curiously it is not displayed in the UI along with the other iCloud Drive root level folders, but you can see it if you search for a file contained within it.)

When you use Wallet in iOS and try to save a file (such as a PDF export from one of your cards), the file is saved to `com~apple~shoebox/Documents/`. There are some support files stored in `com~apple~shoebox/UbiquitousCards/`, which seems to only contain a few logos and icons for Wallet items.

Only took more than 10 years to get an answer this one! There is not even a single other hit on the Internet for this :)